# Why can I not change file/folder permissions even after taking ownership?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012

I have a folder hierarchy that has a mess of different permissions. As the the domain `Administrator` group is not included in this list, I kept receiving an error when attempting to change the permissions.

A bit of scouring the web uncovered that I would first have to take ownership of the files using the `TAKEOWN` command with the `/r` flag.

Well, I can say that `TAKEOWN` worked wonderfully, but I am still encountering the same issue whereby I receive an `Error Applying Changes` alert.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Upon running the `icalcs` command on the directory to update permissions after the ownership had been changed, passed ignore success, and continue on failure flags, then piped the output to a text file.

The permissions were unable to be changed because the file paths to some of the shared folders were too long.

I have not rectified the issue yet, but my approach will likely be to use the `subst` command to mount a valid UNC path and temporarily assign it to a local drive letter, then update the permissions with `icacls`.